# Why do shelves often fall during the night?

Tags: shelving

I was reading [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/163695/how-do-i-reattach-a-shelf-to-the-wall-when-it-ripped-out-of-the-wall) question and ran across something that has occurred to me several times in the past.  It may just be that it seems like shelves fall at night a disproportionate amount of the time but from past experience, I have had no less than four shelves fall in multiple locations, all at night.  Is there a good reason why shelves appear to fall at night more often than during the day or is it just random chance.

Comment: This is just speculation, but thermal expansion and contraction may play a role -- as the fasteners cool off at night, they slightly shrink and thus may not hold as well.  But the details will depend a lot on how the shelf was installed in the first place.

Comment: I think it's associated with a corollary to Murphy's Law stating that bad things happen when it causes the most disruption to your life. So waking you up at night can fit that category, but only if you MUST sleep that night... Seriously though, houses expand and contract with ambient temperature, which is why you often hear them creak and pop at night.

Comment: If a tree falls in the forest...

Comment: Sounds like the bread falling buttered side down (is proportional to the cost of the carpet)...

Comment: Night is when toys and other household items come to life and them moving is going to put more stress on a shelf than a static load.